# ExtJs : set system date as label text in a form panel

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I am using ExtJs and I have a form as following.

```
var tourPlanForm = new Ext.form.FormPanel({
bodyStyle : {
    "background-color" : "#000000",
    "padding" : "10px"
},
layout : {
    type : 'vbox',
    // pack:'end'
    align : 'center'
},
defaults : {
    labelWidth : 140,
    padding : '10 0 0 0'
},

items : [ {
    xtype : 'compositefield',
    labelWidth : 120,
    items : [ {
        xtype : 'label',
        text : 'SystemDate',
        forId : 'myFieldId',
        style : 'marginleft:10px'

    }, ]
}

],
buttons : [ {
    text : 'New',
    handler : function() {

        var sysDate = new Date();
        //alert(sysDate);
        var lbTourCode = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('form > compositefield > label')[1];
        console.log(lbTourCode);
        lbTourCode.setText(sysDate);
    }
}]
});
```

My form has a new button and a label. I need to set system date as the label text when user clicks the new button. I've used

```
var lbTourCode = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('form > compositefield > label')[1];
        console.log(lbTourCode);
        lbTourCode.setText(sysDate);
```

But it doesn't work. Firebug console says

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('form > compositefield > label')[1]; not define
```

I would be much appreciate if anyone please be so kind enough to explain what's wrong with this and how should I overcome this issue.

Thank You

Answer (score 2):

Array's are zero based, possibly your item is located:

```
Ext.ComponentQuery.query('form > compositefield > label')[0]
```

Additionally, adding an `itemId` to a component can make it easier to query later (you additionally have an extra comma in the item array which can cause issues in some browsers):

```
items : [ {
        xtype : 'label',
        text : 'SystemDate',
        forId : 'myFieldId',
        style : 'marginleft:10px',
        itemId:'myLabelField'
    } ]
```

To query later by `itemId`:

```
var field = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#myLabelField')[0];
```

Comment: **TypeError: Ext.ComponentQuery is undefined
 

var tourCode = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#idTourCode')[0];**

Comment: Sorry, `Ext.ComponentQuery.query` is 4.0.  I'm not as familiar with Ext 3.0 but accorinding to docs you can assign an `id`(instead of `itemId`) and query with Ext.getCmp('idTourCode'). More info available in [sencha docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext-method-getCmp)